# Using Basic Auth from requests.auth library and unsure if authentication is succeeding

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script to login to icloud and scrape a note that I keep on my phone and keep a log of it on my pc. I've gotten this far, but I don't know how to verify that the authentication was successful. For obvious reasons I left my username and password out of the code below

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

URL = "https://www.icloud.com/"
login = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
page = requests.get(URL)
```

I tried printing the page status code with and without the correct user info but got 200 both times

Comment: You probably get the same basic top page as if you open icloud.com in your browser. I doubt the page uses Basic HTTP auth, your auth header is probably just getting ignored.

Comment: You're not using *login*

Answer (score -1):

When you're working with Basic Auth in Python using the **'requests'** library, you've got to make sure you're actually sending your login details with your request. From what you've shown, it looks like you've set up your **'HTTPBasicAuth'** object correctly, but you're not using it in your **'requests.get()'** call. You need to pass it as an argument to the auth parameter.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

URL = "https://www.icloud.com/"
login = HTTPBasicAuth('your_username', 'your_password')
page = requests.get(URL, auth=login)

print(page.status_code)
```

Replace **'your_username'** and **'your_password'** with your actual iCloud credentials. When you run this, the status code will tell you if the login was successful. Normally, a 200 status code means success, and a 401 means unauthorized (wrong credentials).

However, keep in mind that iCloud might not support Basic Auth. It's a bit simple and not super secure for a service like iCloud, which probably uses something more robust like OAuth. Basic Auth might not cut it here, so if you're still having trouble, you might need to look into how iCloud handles its authentication.